# SSL/TLS enabling in ElasticSearch 6.2.4

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

We are using elastic-search-6.2.4 for our product and currently it is working with HTTP. Now we have a requirement to configure the same elastic-search-6.2.4 with HTTPS. I went through the several blogs on elastic search website but found out that it is available in the latest version but is there any way if i could configure HTTPS in 6.2.4 as well? Please help me out.

Comment: You will need to upgrade or buy a license, the security features that you need to implemente TLS in Elasticsearch are free only on 6.8+ (6.X branch) and on 7.1+ (7.X branch), your best approach is to upgrade to 6.8 and follow the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/get-started-enable-security.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful information.